# Highcharts Stacked Column Charts with Database Data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

we show the data from the database as a highchart column chart in the following method.

```
$Data .= "[Date.UTC(".$year.",".($month-1).",".$day.",".$hour."),".$DB['DATA']."],";
```

.

```
    var charteng = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'containereng',
        type: 'column',
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },title: {
        text: 'Title Description',
        style: {
        color: '#000000',
    },
    },yAxis: {
        labels: {
        format: '{value} km'
      },title: {
            text: 'km'
        }
    },xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
    },series: [{
        showInLegend: false,
        name: 'km',
        data: <?=$Data ?>
    }],
  });
```

But the data comes from more than one source. The current chart shows the sum of data coming from different sources at the same time.

But I want to see the data of each source separately as below. Every source has a different id number.

http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/qyfky/

I want chart to be like this => prnt.sc/htbytq

Can you help me?

Comment: In which property/variable is the id of the data source saved?

Comment: Hi Kamil, the table structure is like the link. I want chart to be like this => https://image.prntscr.com/image/pMAXF4BoTBShqbCzO7EH0g.png
I want to see the data of each device separately in the stacking column chart.

Comment: You can preprocess your data like this: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/vjgayr39/